# Regular expression for untypical parentheses

Tags: regex, grok

Example input:

```
Ala ma kota (ASD defect - 7) kot ma ale.
```

Ideal output:

```
(ASD defect - 7)
```

How to parse this text from parentheses?

Comment: What language/regex flavor? Can there be nested parentheses? What did you try? (Prosimy o szczegóły)

Comment: I am trying to buid GROK pattern with regexp (https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: What about `\((?<name>[^()]*)\)`? Or - including the parentheses - `(?<name>\([^()]*\))`?

Comment: You are so good ! Thank you !. Do you have any idea how to read only 12345678 from [wid:12345678,sid:345] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grok, you'd need the following regex with a named capture group:

```
\((?<name>[^()]*)\)
```

This will match a text inside parentheses excluding parentheses. To include them, just put them into the capturing group:

```
(?<name>\([^()]*\))
```

The negated character class `[^()]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `)` and `(`.

**UPDATE**:

As for using nested capturing groups, here is an example:

```
(?<sth2>\bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+))
```

[image]

Comment: A bonus answer: `\bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+)`.

Comment: \bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+) works fine here: https://regex101.com/, but I have starnge problem to makes from them GROK pattern...

Comment: You need to be more explicit, post your tries to the question and explain what works and what does not.

Comment: hmmm... for example (?<sth2>\bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+)) doesn't work in grok debugger

Comment: Problem related probably with grok, when input: [wid:150,sn:ala] and pattern: \bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+) \bsn:\s*(?<sn>\w+) - output: No matches

Comment: Well, according to [Oniguruma regex syntax](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt), this should be correct: `\bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+),sn:\s*(?<sn>\w+)` with `[wid:150,sn:ala]`. Perhaps, there are other patterns that prevent this one from firing.

Comment: I have with problem with (ALA def - 7) [wid:1506, sn:ala] and pattern  (?<thread>\([^()]*\)) \bwid:\s*(?<wid>\d+), \bsn:\s*(?<sn>\w+), something wrong behind '- 7)'

Comment: I think you are looking for `(?<thread>\([^()]*\))\s*\[wid:\s*(?<wid>\d+),\s*sn:\s*(?<sn>\w+)`.